# Jboss AS 7 not deploying giving Servlet exception from rt.jar(1.6.0_20)

Tags: java, web-applications, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x

```
17:34:55,756 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Hello.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Hello.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "Hello.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class com.infotech.hello.web.util.CacheApplicationData with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.Hello.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ServletException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServletException from [Module "deployment.Hello.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 15 more
```

i am not understanding the reason for this error 
"**Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ServletException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]**"

Comment: You have posted this same question a month ago @ https://community.jboss.org/thread/214137 , and I ask you the same question that those fellow members asked , 1) where is `com.infotech.hello.web.util.CacheApplicationData` and also , 2) do a jar -tf <your war file> and attach the output here (this command will give you the structure of your war

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved that error. there was duplicate servlet api jars present in my workspace.i removed them and that servlet exception went away.

thanks for ur support :)